# how do I insert flag by each country name in select option using angular

Tags: angularjs

I see a lot of answers but no one work for me.

Answers i found:

option 1:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">choose country</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.name}}" ng-style="background:url('../images/flage/+item.name+.png')>{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

option 2:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">choose country</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.name}}" ng-style="background:url('../images/flage/+{{item.name}}+.png')>{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

option 3 :

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">choose country</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.name}}" data-image="('../images/flage/item.name.png')">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

option 4 :

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">choose country</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.name}}" data-image="('../images/flage/{{item.name}}.png')">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

someone know how to do it?

Comment: can you tell what u want and what is not happening?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.countries = [
    {
      'name':'india',
      'flag':'http://pngimg.com/upload/flags_PNG14694.png'
    },
        {
      'name':'USA',
      'flag':'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png'
    }
    ]
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" name="country" ng-model="user.country">
            <option value="">choose country</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in countries" value="{{item.name}}" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{item.flag}})'}">{{item.name}}</option>
        </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What output you want ?

Comment: no example without images inside. the example does not do what i wanted. @tom moc